# can't put <div> on new line without other elements floating left

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of `<ul>`s that I am setting to `float:left`. I would like my div `.title` to be placed on a new line after the `<ul>`'s without there being a float left property applied in relation to the preceding `<ul>`'s. How can I do this?

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xpawc1uw/8/

Here is my CODE:

CSS:

```css
    .center-div ul {
       float: left;
       width: 245px;
     }

    .title{
      position:relative;
      width:100%;
      left:0px; 
      top:140px;
     } 

HTML:
```

```html
    <div class='center-div hidden'> 
        <ul></ul>
        <ul></ul>
        <ul></ul>
        <div class="title">My title hopefully left justified</div>
        <ul></ul>
        <ul></ul>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your JSFiddle and get this working:

```
    .center-div {
      background: #cfcfcf;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 40px;
      display: block;
    }

   .center-div {
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    .center-div ul {
      float: left;
      width: 245px;
    }
    .title{
      clear: both;
    }
```

When you use `clear: both;` you are saying, I don't want anything in the left and right side of my html component.

Answer (score 1):

```
.title{display:block;clear:both}  /* and no more property like as relative position */
```